# How to add conditional statement to React data.map function

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements

I'm a React newbie and have a component which is outputting a checkbox list by mapping an array. This is the code that presently works.

```
    export default class First extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
        super(props);
       this.state = {
          data: data,
     };
    }

    render() {
       return (
        <div>
          {this.state.data.map(d =>
             <label key={ d.name } className="control control--checkbox">{d.name}
             <input type="checkbox"/>
             <div className="control__indicator"></div>
            </label>)}
       </div>
        );
    }
  }
```

What I need to do is add an if/else telling the return map function only to render the checkbox list if another variable in the array (called domain) = "HMO". I'm really struggling with the syntax. I think it needs to be inserted below the {this.state.data.map(d => line but am really stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for something like this.

```
export default class First extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   this.state = {
      data: data,
 };
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.data.map(d => {
        if(d.domain === "HMO"){
          return (
           <label key={ d.name } className="control control--checkbox">{d.name}
             <input type="checkbox"/>
             <div className="control__indicator" />
           </label>
         )}
        return null
      })}
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The .map function will iterate through each element in your data array, it will then check if that element's domain variable is equal to the string "HMO".  If it is, it will return the html that displays the checkbox, otherwise it will return null.

Comment: This worked best for me, although the syntax (return within return etc.) was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
export default class First extends React.Component {

    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this.state = {
            data: data
        };
    }

    getItems() {
        return this.state.data
            .filter(d.domain === "HMO")
            .map(d => (
                <label key={ d.name } className="control control--checkbox">{d.name}
                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                    <div className="control__indicator"></div>
                </label>
            ));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.getItems()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The downside is that you loop twice compared to @MEnf's solution so it can be slower if you have a really long array. The upside is that it looks neater (I know that is quite subjective).